# jQuery validation errors are not shown when I'm not using a submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

[Check out this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ajeyot/6).

I have a form with a custom button that submits it via ajax (not a real submit button).
I'm using jquery-validation to validate the form, and running `validate().checkForm()` to validate it.

My question is - why don't the error messages on the specific fields appear when I do this? They appear all right when I'm using a standard submit button.

Edit: My example doesn't include the ajax submission, but just pretend it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because validate is listening for the submit event.

If you add `$("form").submit();` inside the click event then it is fired.

http://jsbin.com/avuhed/edit#javascript,html,live

Answer (score 0):

Piggy-backing on what @weezer said, you'll need to associate the form submission event with the button click, and you'll also want to put it inside the form itself.  Right now it's sitting outside of it.  For future updates, and sanity, it'll make your life easier to keep it grouped together.

Comment: Are you saying that the JS should be inside the form?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the button element should be inside the form.

Answer (score -1):

The jquery validation is triggered by a standard form submit.

You may need to attach a .click handler to your custom submit button as so:

```
    var isValid = $("#yourForm").valid();

                if(isValid) {
// Do stuff
    }
```

Yes, i have and if you put:

```
$("#submit").click(function() { 
    var isValid = $("#form").isValid(); 
    if(isValid) {  
      alert('test'); 
    } 
});
```

Instead of what you have and move the custom button **within** the form, the validation works. http://jsbin.com/ajeyot/9

Comment: Yes, i have and if you put $("#submit").click(function() {
    var isValid = $("#form").isValid();
  if(isValid) {
      alert('test');
  }
}); instead of what you have and move the custom button **within** the form, the validation works.

http://jsbin.com/ajeyot/9/

Comment: Sorry .. if you edit your answer to include this suggestion, I'll upvote it (I can't right now until it's edited).